KKT counter example
Yesterday I was going deep into the KKT theorem and there is one thing left I can't prove for myself.
So, we are given $\hat{x}$ which is already not a minimum of the objective convex programming problem. Although at the same time we have a non-zero set of Lagrange coefficients (non-zero!) $(\lambda_0, ..., \lambda_m)$ which satisfies KKT conditions. Does anyone know such an example of the CP problem?

not clearly what you're asking. $\hat{x}$ is NOT a minimum, and you have nonzero dual variables associated with what?

@GBmath Well, I want to know whether there exists a correct CP problem for which all the conditions are satisfied but $\hat{x}$ is not a minimum.

I don't think you can find such an example. If $\hat{x}$ and $\lambda$ satisfy the KKT for CP, then they are primal-dual optimal
